How many seconds to wait before creating an ARB subscription from a new customer payment profile in authorize.net?
When creating a subscription in authorize.net via API You are required to wait X amount of seconds after creating a customer payment profile before you can create the subscription. If not, You will get the error, Record cannot be found. It works to create a transaction immediately but the subscription fails unless I wait 10 seconds. The flow goes like this, 1. create a customer payment profile. 2. create a transaction with that customer payment profile. 3. Wait X amount of seconds (Im doing 10 seconds). 4. Make the api call to create the ARB subscription. Is 10 seconds a safe amount to wait? what is everyone else doing? Here is my code for the payment flow.

 const environment = 'SANDBOX';

  const { dispatchData } = useAcceptJs({ environment, authData });



  const createTransaction = async (customerPaymentProfileId, planId) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/charge-customer-profile-tp`,
        { customerPaymentProfileId, planId },  // Only send the planId
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating transaction:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const createSubscription = async (customerPaymentProfileId, planId) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/create-subscription-from-profile-tp`,
        { paymentProfileId: customerPaymentProfileId, planId },  // Only send the planId
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating subscription:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const createTransactionAndSubscription = async (customerPaymentProfileId, plan) => {
    setProcessingMessage('Processing...');
    try {
      // Pass only the planId, no nested plan structure
      const planId = isYearly ? plan?.planId?.yearly : plan?.planId?.monthly;

      const transactionResult = await createTransaction(customerPaymentProfileId, planId);
      console.log("transactionResult", transactionResult.response)
      if (transactionResult.response.code === 'Response Code: 1') {

        // Wait for 5 seconds before creating the subscription (bcuz authnet is a slow POS api and needs time before a subscription can be created with a newly created payment profile)
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));

        console.log("transactionResult.code ======>", transactionResult.response.code)
        console.log("customerPaymentProfileId", customerPaymentProfileId)
        const subscriptionResult = await createSubscription(customerPaymentProfileId, planId);

        if (
          subscriptionResult.response.messages.resultCode === 'Ok' &&
          subscriptionResult.response.subscriptionId
        ) {
          setProcessingMessage("You're all set!");
          setProcessing(false);
        } else {
          setProcessingMessage(
            'Your credits have been added and your initial payment was accepted. However, there was an issue creating your subscription. Please contact support within the next 30 days to update your subscription.'
          );
          setProcessing(false);
        }
      } else {
        setProcessingMessage('There was an error processing your first payment.');
        setProcessing(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in transaction and subscription:', error);
      setProcessingMessage('An error occurred during the process.');
      setProcessing(false);
    }
  };


  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Validate inputs
    const newErrors = {};
    if (!profileValues.street1 && cardToUse === "showCardForm") {
      newErrors.street1 = 'Street is required';
    }
    if (!profileValues.city && cardToUse === "showCardForm") {
      newErrors.city = 'City is required';
    }
    if (!profileValues.state && cardToUse === "showCardForm") {
      newErrors.state = 'State is required';
    }
    if (!profileValues.zip && cardToUse === "showCardForm") {
      newErrors.zip = 'ZIP Code is required';
    }
    if (!profileValues.country && cardToUse === "showCardForm") {
      newErrors.country = 'Country is required';
    }
    if (!cardData.cardNumber && cardToUse === "showCardForm") {
      newErrors.cardNumber = 'Card Number is required';
    }
    if ((!cardData.month || !cardData.year) && cardToUse === "showCardForm") {
      newErrors.expDate = 'Expiration Date is required';
    }
    if (!cardData.cardCode && cardToUse === "showCardForm") {
      newErrors.cardCode = 'CVC is required';
    }

    // If there are errors, set the errors state and return
    if (Object.keys(newErrors).length > 0) {
      setErrors(newErrors);
      return;
    }

    // Clear errors
    setErrors({});

    try {

      if (cardToUse === 'showCardForm') {
        const response = await dispatchData({ cardData, billingDetails: profileValues });
        setNonceResponse(response);
        return;
      } else {
        setProcessing(true);
        await createTransactionAndSubscription(cardToUse, plan);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error in onSubmit:', err);
      setFailedCard(true);
      setProcessing(false);
    }
  };




  useEffect(() => {
    if (nonceResponse) {
      setProcessing(true);
      const handlePaymentProfileCreation = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/create-cust-pay-profile-tp`, // I beleive its ok to use this same route for follow up and trustpro
            { nonceResponse, billingDetails: profileValues },
            { withCredentials: true }
          );

          if (
            response.data.response.messages.message[0].code === 'I00001' &&
            response.data.response.customerPaymentProfileId
          ) {
            const customerPaymentProfileId = response.data.response.customerPaymentProfileId;
            await createTransactionAndSubscription(customerPaymentProfileId, plan);
          } else {
            setFailedCard(true);
            setProcessing(false);
            setShowSubModal(false);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error creating payment profile:', error);
          setFailedCard(true);
          setProcessing(false);
          setShowSubModal(false);
        }
      };

      handlePaymentProfileCreation();
    }
  }, [nonceResponse, plan, setShowSubModal]);




